# Confused about purpose of this PHP function

Tags: php

This was on a PHP test and I really have no idea the purpose of this function:

```
function myFunction (int x)
{
  if ((x & 1) == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any help explaining this would be lovely

Comment: It's an odd function. Maybe this will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: And not a valid PHP function _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'x' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)_

Comment: What inputs have you tried and what outputs do you get back? If you can describe the pattern, then you know what the function does :)

Answer (score 0):

It just checks if the value is an EVEN number or not.

e.g.

```
myFunction(3); //this would be false
myFunction(4); //this would be true
```